# Iterate over list of dataframes and drop specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes:

```
list = [a, b, c, d, e ,f]
```

Each of these dataframes has a column called 'PEOPLE', and I want to loop through this list and drop any rows in any of the data frames where the value in 'PEOPLE' is one of the values in another list:

`people_to_drop = ['PERSON ABC','PERSON DEF']`

I've been trying the following method:

```
for index,item in enumerate(list):
     list[index] = item[~item['PEOPLE'].isin(people_to_drop)].copy()
```

However, when I check the datasets after the for loop has run, they don't seem to have dropped the rows I want dropped. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try list comprehension as follows

```
df_list = [a, b, c, d, e ,f]
new_df_list = [a_df[~a_df['PEOPLE'].isin(people_to_drop)].copy() for a_df in df_list]
```

After that, print out each dataframe in `new_df_list` to check

```
print(new_df_list[0])
print(new_df_list[1])
```

Comment: Will this modify the underlying variables? Basically, I'm using the list as a way to iterate over a set of key datasets I want to clean up, but I want to make sure I can reference the original variable names throughout the script.

Comment: No. It is the reason I use `.copy` on each sliced/dropped-row dataframe inside list comprehension to make sure that a new copy of sliced/filtered dataframe is created. `new_df_list` is a complete new list of dropped-row dataframes.

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as variable name. It will over-shadow the python built-in `list`